# How to tag the version in the origin of git?

Tags: git

Github doesnt have a way to tag via the web UI.

I have a version of the code checked out and updated.  Beofre I push much updated master to the origin, I need to tag the origin in case I ever need to go back to that release version.

The question is,how do I do it, with out tagging, or pushing, my modfied commmited (local) changes?

I guess one strategy would be to clone the repo in a different directory, tag that, then work out how to push the tag back into the main repo (orogin).

I am an SVN expert, to do this in SVN is trivial - you can tag the remote head without affecting current code without issue, but with git its much more involved.  Tortoise git only seems to allow you to take the local (modified) version.

To make it more complicated, I seem to have tagged the local version at some poin with the tag I want, but I cant be sure thats the same as the current version in the origin. I guess my local tags dont get pushed into the repo by default - I assumed they would.  Thus I may end up with duplicate tags, if I checkout the origin, tag, push tag, then push my local modifiect version which also has the same tag?

Sorry for my lack of knowledge on git.

I did the workaround option - checkout the repo in a new dir, tag, push with --tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which commit is tagged.

Go on github to find the hash of the commit you want to tag (let's say it's `01e7e654`), and use :

```
git tag -a v1.0 01e7e654
git push --tags
```

Comment: Looks useful, but I dont know what he commit_hash is for the version which is current the master in the repo.